# Load two json files of Arrays of Dictionaries. Add missing dictionaries from the file A to file B

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I need to sync two json files to add new content from **File A** (located in the app bundle) to **File B** after an app update.

Both json files are arrays of dictionaries. I need to iterate the dictionaries form **File A**, and based on the "id" value, if a dictionary is not present in **File B** I need to append those missing dictionaries and save **File B** back to the file system.

I have a solution below that does this, and seems to work. But it's SO ugly! Granted I put this together in about 15 minutes cringing the whole way but I'm sure there has to be a better way of handling this. Also, I don't want to further muddy the waters by converting these dictionaries to structs or models for the comparison only to convert them back to dictionaries -> json.

Any advise here would be great! I prefer clean code and this is a mess.

```
typealias JSON = [[String: Any]]
static private func uglySync() {
    let fileName: String = "someFileName"
    guard let sourceUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json") else { return }
    guard let destinationDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
    let destinationUrl = destinationDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Data/" + fileName + ".json")

    do {
        let sourceData = try Data(contentsOf: sourceUrl)
        do {
            if let sourceArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: sourceData, options: .mutableContainers) as? JSON {
                do {
                    let destinationData = try Data(contentsOf:  destinationUrl)
                    do {
                        if let destinationArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: destinationData, options: .mutableContainers) as? JSON {
                            var mutableArray = destinationArray
                            sourceArray.forEach({ (item) in
                                if let itemId = item["id"] as? String {
                                    let foundItem = destinationArray.filter { $0["id"] as! String == itemId }.first
                                    if foundItem == nil {
                                        mutableArray.append(item)
                                    }
                                }
                            })

                            do {
                                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: mutableArray, options: .prettyPrinted)
                                try jsonData.write(to: destinationUrl)
                            } catch let error as NSError {
                                print("Couldn't write to file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        } else {
                            print("Cound not process json")
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            } else {
                print("Cound not process json")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    // oh wow the try catches :/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've grouped converting the files to jsonArray to simplify the do...catch. Alternatively, if you don't need to print the error message, you could opt to have Optional `try?` as well to remove the do...catch block.

```
typealias JSONArray = [[String: Any]]

private func jsonArray(from fileURL: URL) -> JSONArray? {
    do {
        let fileData: Data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        guard let jsonArray = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: fileData, options: .mutableContainers)) as? JSONArray else {
            debugPrint("Failed to find JSON Array table")
            return nil
        }

        return jsonArray
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
}

func sync() {
    let fileName: String = "someFileName"

    guard
        let fileURL: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json"),
        let destinationDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first,
        let destinationURL: URL = destinationDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Data/" + fileName + ".json"),
        let sourceArray = jsonArray(from: fileURL),
        let destinationArray = jsonArray(from: destinationURL)
    else {
        return
    }

    var mutableArray = destinationArray
    let destinationIDArray = destinationArray.compactMap { $0["id"] as? String }

    mutableArray.forEach { (item) in
        if let itemId = item["id"] as? String, !(destinationIDArray.contains { $0 == itemId }) {
            mutableArray.append(item)
        }
    }

    // Update File
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: mutableArray, options: .prettyPrinted)
        try jsonData.write(to: destinationURL)
    } catch {
        print("Couldn't write to file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this solution! I've added this to my project and after a few small tweaks it works great. Clean and easy to read. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put the different `try`s in the same `do` block.

```
do {
  try function1()
  try function2()
} catch {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

So afterwards your function may look like

```
    typealias JSON = [[String: Any]]
    static private func moderatelyOkSync() {
        let fileName: String = "someFileName"
        guard let sourceUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json") else { return }
        guard let destinationDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
        let destinationUrl = destinationDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Data/" + fileName + ".json")

        do {
            let sourceData = try Data(contentsOf: sourceUrl)
            if let sourceArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: sourceData, options: .mutableContainers) as? JSON {
                let destinationData = try Data(contentsOf:  destinationUrl)
            }
            var mutableArray = destinationArray
            sourceArray.forEach({ (item) in
                if let itemId = item["id"] as? String {
                    let foundItem = destinationArray.filter { $0["id"] as! String == itemId }.first
                    if foundItem == nil {
                        mutableArray.append(item)
                    }
                }
            })
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: mutableArray, options: .prettyPrinted)
            try jsonData.write(to: destinationUrl)

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Very true. I was being a bit verbose. What are your thoughts on the load / compare / save aspects? Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: @mejim707 The saving and loading looks ok too, maybe extract it out to a separate function. Compare is not too shabby either.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is to Decode the json files with struct and then encode(serialization) it to the other files. Because the code to do that would be a 2 liner, but you would first have to layout all the variables in the struct. Probably still not optimal